# JQuery DataTables - Hide Table Until Searching

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm using DataTables with JQuery to show some data on my site. I use the search feature to filter the data, and give me the intended results. What I'd like to do is to hide the table until a user begins typing a search in the box, and only then display the proper results. Here's my DataTables code right now:

```
    function renderTable() {
        jQuery('.dataTable').show();
        jQuery('.dataTables_info').show();
        jQuery('.dataTables_paginate').show();
    }

    function hideTable() {
        jQuery('.dataTable').hide();
        jQuery('.dataTables_info').hide();
        jQuery('.dataTables_paginate').hide();
    }

    jQuery('.dataTables_filter input').keypress(function() {
        if (jQuery('.dataTables_filter input').val() != '') {
            renderTable();
        } else {
            hideTable();
        }
    });

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery('#resultsTable').DataTable({
            "paging": true,
            "pageLength": 25,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "pagingStyle": "simple_numbers",
            "language": {
                "search": "",
                "searchPlaceholder": "Search for an entry"
            },
            "order": [1, 'asc']
        });

        hideTable();

    } );
```

It successfully hides everything from the DataTable but the searchbox on document.ready, but I can't get it to call my renderTables() function when a user clicks in the box and types. I'm not sure if I'm targeting it correctly with: '.dataTables_filter input'. The search input that DataTables renders doesn't have any unique ID I can target, so I have to refer to it from the filter element which contains it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try some thing like this:

Make a function to render the datatable with the required filter parameter and call it on search functionality. So that it cannot render table on page load. When your search functionality is initiated it will render the table with the filter parameter.

Ex:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search_box').keyup(function(){
        var searchStr = $(this).val();

        if((searchStr).length)
        {
            filterData();   // call the filter function with required parameters
        }
        else
        {
            // empty the table body
        }
    });
});

function filterData()
{
    // your code
}
```

Comment: I updated my code with my newest attempt. I think this is roughly what you were getting at, but I'm having trouble getting it to watch the input field correctly. I'd like to check it when a user types in it. If it has content at that point, I'll show the table and pagination, if they've just deleted their search or never typed one, I'd like it to be hidden. Please let me know what you see in my new code that's wrong. Thanks!

Comment: This worked when I moved the keyup() watch into my document.ready block. If you update your answer to reflect that they keyup() chunk should be within the document.ready check, I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rendered filter input box, then use the drawback function. This is how I did it.

```
    drawCallback: function(settings){
            if($('#yourtableid_filter input').val().length > 0) --this is generated by datatable
            {
                $('#yourtableid tr').show();
            } else {
                $('#yourtableid tr').hide();
            }
        }
```

once the filter input is empty, it will hide everything again.