# Only show datatables data when searched

Tags: javascript, datatables

How can I make it work to *hide data* in the Datatables? I want it only to show the data when searched.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery DataTables - Hide Table Until Searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078316/jquery-datatables-hide-table-until-searching)

Comment: I think the datatable with AJAX will help you. On load don't load any data and on search get the records using AJAX call. eaxmple, https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side